# Headless Chrome browser fail to launch on windows container?

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm using windows nanoserver container to launch puppeteer but it fails and I'm not sure what's wrong with my code

here's my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1903

COPY nodejs /windows/system32
CMD [ "node.exe" ]

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "./server.js" ]
```

nodejs  is a the node folder on my machine

and here's my package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "puppeteer": "^5.5.0",
        "@axe-core/puppeteer": "^4.1.0"
    }
}
```

and here's my server.js

```
const { AxePuppeteer } = require('@axe-core/puppeteer');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true,
                ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
            args: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
            });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
 
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/');
 
  const results = await new AxePuppeteer(page).analyze();
  
  console.log(results);
 
  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
})();
```

So if I build the docker image then run

```
docker build -t chromeHeadless
docker run chromeHeadless
```

I get this error

```
(node:1228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (C:\app\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\BrowserRunner.js:193:20)           at Interface.<anonymous> (C:\app\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\BrowserRunner.js:183:68)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:424:8)
    at Socket.onend (readline.js:202:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1244:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1228) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```